# Graph Theory and vertices

Tags: graph-theory

For each of the graphs described below, state whether or not such a graph exists. For those that do exist, draw an example of such a graph. For those that do not exist, explain why they do not exist.

**(a) A simple graph with 7 vertices with degrees 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1**
Answer: 19 degrees therefore doesnt exist, the degrees must be even.

**(b) A simple graph with 7 vertices with degrees 6, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1 that is not connected.**

**(c) A simple graph with 7 vertices with degrees 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 that contains no closed Euler trail.**

Answer
Theorem: you cant have a vertex with a degree of 2 if it isnt connecting another vertex therefore all vertices must connect atleast one other therefore a euler trail will exist.

**(d) A simple graph with 8 vertices with degrees 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 that is a tree.**

Exists , just drew this one out

**(e) A simple graph with 8 vertices with degrees 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 that is connected.**

this must contain 14 degrees rather contains 12

While i understand the concept Im not sure if my explanation is sufficient or right

Comment: Your answer to (c) is wrong. Can you draw a simple graph with 3 vertices with degrees 2, 2, 2? OK, now can you draw a simple graph with 4 vertices with degrees 2, 2, 2, 2? OK, now put the two drawings side by side. Do you see 7 vertices with degrees 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2? Can you draw a closed Euler trail?>

Comment: couldnt you just draw 7 vertices connecting each other? im not sure i follow

Comment: Sure, you can draw "7 vertices connecting each other", but that's not what problem (c) asks for. It asks you if you can draw a graph with 7 vertices, all of degree 2, which contains **no** closed Euler trail. And I just showed you how to draw one.

Comment: i think you mis-interpreted my answer :P im also saying a graph with a closed euler trail therefore the statement is wrong :P

Comment: You lost me. Part (c) asks, does there exist a simple graph with 7 vertices and degrees 2,2,2,2,2,2,2 that contains no closed Euler trail. I showed you how to draw a simple graph with 7 vertices and degrees 2,2,2,2,2,2,2 that contains no closed Euler trail. What statement is wrong??

Comment: i think i might be confusing the definition of a closed euler trail.

wouldnt the triangle with 3 vertices be the closed euler trail ?

Comment: An [Euler trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) has to use **every** edge of the graph once and only once. The triangle with 3 vertices would be a closed Euler trail if the 3 vertices and 3 edges of the triangle were THE WHOLE GRAPH. The graph we're talking about has 7 vertices and SEVEN EDGES. An Euler trail for that graph would have to use all 7 edges.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct on part (A).

In (B) such a graph is not possible. Because if you look at the vertex that has degree 6 it must be connected with all the other vertices in the graph. But then there is a vertex of degree 5 it will be connected to the degree 6 vertex plus 4 other vertices. But there are two vertices of degree 1 that are already exhausted by the degree 6 vertex hence such a connection is not possible.

For part (C) such a graph is possible. As an example you have $C_3 \cup C_4$.

For part (E) your judgement is right for such a graph of order 8 to be connected it must at least have 7 edges $\implies$ the sum of degrees of vertices must be at least 14.

Comment: for e) where you count the degrees with respect to edges and vertices, is that only for trees or is that for any graph

Comment: or is it that if ANY graph is connected, its automatically a tree?

Comment: I have edited that part.

Comment: Another definition of a tree is a connected graph with no cycles.